# "haver-se com" e "avir-se com"

Tags: significado, tradução-inglês, diferenças, verbo-frasal

Eu gostaria de saber o significado de “haver-se com” e “avir-se com”, neste contexto:

> Ela terá de se haver com o pai.
>
> Ela terá de se avir com o pai.

Achei o texto [neste site](http://www.curso-objetivo.br/vestibular/bom_portugues/021202.aspx).

Eu já entendi que as duas frases têm o mesmo sentido neste caso e que elas em outros casos têm significados diferentes, mas simplesmente não consigo com nenhum dicionário ou corpus achar o significado que elas têm aqui. Tentei com linguee.com e [Priberam](http://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/haver).

Espero que alguém possa me ajudar.

Comment: Você quer a tradução disso para o inglês, é isso? Acho que seria "come to terms with" em ambos os casos.

Comment: Valeu, bfavaretto, qualquer coisa que me faz entender melhor ajuda.

Comment: Akitirija, o *de* está associado ao *ter* e não ao *haver* ou *avir*: ***tenho de** acabar este trabalho, **tenho de** acordar cedo amanhã*, etc.; e *haver-se* e *avir-se* podem ser usados no mesmo sentido sem o *ter de*: por exemplo, *ela que **se haja** com o pai*. (E tens de escrever um "@" nos nomes, @bfavaretto, no teu comentário acima, para a pessoa ser notificada.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Os dois verbos partilham vários mas não todos os significados aplicáveis às frases apresentadas, pelo que não é possível garantir que elas sejam equivalentes. O Aulete explica [*avir*](http://www.aulete.com.br/avir) e [*haver* (significados 16 e 17)](http://www.aulete.com.br/haver), e eu deixo aqui as definições do Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003):

> **avir** *v* **1** *t.d. e pron.* pôr(-se) em harmonia com; conciliar(-se) <*fez tudo para avi-los*> <*avieram-se após longa conversa*> **2** *pron.* diligenciar por resolver pendências; entrar em entendimento; entender-se <*os funcionários descontentes foram avir-se com o patrão*> **3** *pron.* adaptar-se, acomodar-se <*teve que se avir com aquela situação*>
>
> **haver** *v* **23** *pron.* ter trato com; lidar <*é melhor havermo-nos com a secretária e não com o ministro*> **24** *pron.* prestar contas a; avir-se <*quem não for já para a cama vai haver-se comigo depois*>

A frase «terá de se *avir* com o pai» é muito atípica. Mas poderíamos imaginar uma situação em que um filho, especialmente adulto, está zangado com o pai, e alguém diz, usando *avir* no sentido 1 do Houaiss, ‘conciliar’:

> Ele terá de se avir com o pai: não pode ficar de relações cortadas com ele para o resto da vida.

***Avir-se*** põe a tónica na conciliação e resolução de desavenças. ***Haver-se*** também pode ser empregue desse modo, mas tem outros significados que *avir-se* não tem. Nomeadamente a construção ***(ter de) se haver com*** é muito usada, mas sobretudo no sentido de ‘prestar contas’ em ameaças ou avisos ominosos, como no exemplo do Houaiss, «*quem não for já para a cama vai haver-se comigo depois*». A ideia é que vem aí reprimenda, castigo, ou alguma outra consequência desagradável. Eis mais alguns exemplos (ênfase minha em todas as citações):

> Alto lá, senhor — bradou uma voz, ao mesmo tempo que uma mão vigorosa agarrava o braço de Luciano… — Que lucro tira o senhor de estar desfeiteando uma criança?... se lhe puser as mãos é comigo que **tem de se haver**. [[Bernardo Guimarães, *O Seminarista*, 2012 (primeira edição de 1872)]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=mYNcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT64&dq=%22se%20lhe%20puser%20as%20m%C3%A3os%20%C3%A9%20comigo%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiGkPeXu_3NAhVC2xoKHbRwA90Q6AEIHTAA#v=onepage&q=%22se%20lhe%20puser%20as%20m%C3%A3os%20%C3%A9%20comigo%22&f=false)
>
> — Em caso algum se trucidarão os feridos e os que se renderem. Somos tropa disciplinada e não bando de malfeitores. Quem desobedecer a estas ordens **terá de se haver comigo**! — avisou João, de catadura turva. [[José Marques Vidal,*A Paixão de Araci*, 2011]](https://books.google.pt/books?id=Mr0YW4lS39AC&pg=PT82&dq=%22ter%C3%A1%20de%20se%20haver%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwieg_rWvf3NAhWK0RoKHYO0Bb4Q6AEIQjAF#v=onepage&q=%22ter%C3%A1%20de%20se%20haver%22&f=false)

Procurei *terá de se haver com* no Google Books, e a grande maioria dos exemplos são ameaças ou avisos. ***Avir-se*** não deve ser usado desta forma, embora se encontre quem o faça. Eis o que diz [Evanildo Bechara na *Moderna Gramática Portuguesa*, 2012](https://books.google.pt/books?id=kA5LywXfV-kC&pg=PT256&dq=%22de%20se%20avir%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiEnqLTq_3NAhUB0xoKHUtiCkMQ6AEILTAA#v=onepage&q=%22de%20se%20avir%22&f=false):

> *Avir-se* é sinônimo de *haver-se*, no sentido 3), isto é, significa *entrar em acordo com, conciliar*
>   […]
>   Erra-se frequentes vezes empregando-se, nas ameaças, *avir-se* por *haver-se*: Ele tem de se *avir* comigo (em lugar de se *haver*).

A frase *terá de se avir com* quase não se encontra, e é portanto bem possível que quem escreveu aquelas duas frases tenha empregue *avir* erradamente no lugar de *haver*.

O verbo *avir* é na verdade muito raro. Procurei neste [Corpus do Português](http://www.corpusdoportugues.org/) todas as ocorrências do verbo *avir*, em qualquer tempo e qualquer pessoa, e encontrei vinte um exemplos do século XIX e apenas três do século XX. Em dois deles, *avir-se* é usado no sentido de ‘entender-se, resolver discórdias’. Por exemplo em [José de Alencar, *O Garatuja*, 2012 (primeira edição de 1873)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=EbtcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT42&dq=%22que%20eu%20em%20brigas%20de%20marido%20e%20mulher%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjuz_eSx_3NAhUBahoKHRcmAUEQ6AEIJjAA#v=onepage&q=%22que%20eu%20em%20brigas%20de%20marido%20e%20mulher%22&f=false), a mãe de Miquelina diz ao genro:

> Está bom, isso é lá com a Miquelina. **Com ela se avenha**, que eu em brigas de marido e mulher não me meto. Só lhe digo que não fui eu quem lha meti a casa, mas o senhor quem andou arrastando-lhe a asa,

Todos os outros exemplos são do tipo *eles que se avenham* ou *ele lá se avenha*. Aqui o sentido é o 3 do Houaiss, ‘adaptar-se, acomodar-se’, mas frequentemente eu diria ‘desenrascar-se’. Nalguns casos de *eles lá se avenham*, também é possível ler o significado ‘entendam-se’. E em todos os casos está implícito, ou por vezes explícito, *arranjem-se vocês, porque eu lavo daí as minhas mãos, não quero ter nada que ver com isso*, tal como deixa entender a mãe da Miquelina no *Garatuja* de Alencar. Este uso está bem explicado no [Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/avir). Alguns exemplos:

> Calma, minha filha! sem calma nada se faz que preste...
>   E, depois de uma meiguice:
>   — Olhe, venha um dia à Sé, confessar-se comigo.. Sua avó encomendou-me uma missa cantada. Não pode haver melhor ocasião... Confesso-a depois da missa. Está dito?
>   — Mas, para quê, dindinho...
>   — Para quê.. é boa! para poder ajudá-la, minha afilhada...
>   — Ora...
>   — Não? pois então **lá se avenham** vocês dois, mas duvido muito que consigam alguma coisa [Aluísio de Azevedo, *O Mulato*](https://books.google.pt/books?id=LXxcAAAAQBAJ&pg=PT377&lpg=PT377&dq=pois%20ent%C3%A3o%20l%C3%A1%20se%20avenham%20voc%C3%AAs%20dois&source=bl&ots=Lq9s4qsG9R&sig=Z80zX5QvPMx_DD3QiulTfUpQnh0&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwiF1IT_zf3NAhWCnRoKHfp1AtcQ6AEIHzAA#v=onepage&q=pois%20ent%C3%A3o%20l%C3%A1%20se%20avenham%20voc%C3%AAs%20dois&f=false)
>
> Raimundo Silva, que justamente se encontra nos lugares da antiga cidade moura, tem, desta coincidência histórica e topográfica, uma consciência múltipla, caleidoscópica, sem dúvida graças à decisão que formalmente tomou de haverem os cruzados resolvido não auxiliar os portugueses, e, portanto, **estes que se avenham** como puderem, com as suas parcas forças nacionais [José Saramago, *História do Cerco de Lisboa*, 1989]

Answer (score 3):

Caso não tenha ficado bem claro nos contextos apresentados as expressões 'ter de se haver com' ou 'ter de se avir com' significam 'ter de se entender com', 'ter de ajustar contas com', 'chegar a um acordo' ou 'dar explicações a'. No sentido de resolver um problema ou um conflito.

Em inglês talvez se possa traduzir como *come to terms with* como sugeriu bfavaretto ou *have to deal with [someone] * ou *have to handle [someone]*.

Comment: não seria "ter de se entender com" ?

Comment: Correcto, tem razão foi erro meu. Já corrigi, obrigado